# Load assembly from Nuget and dependencies

Tags: powershell, nuget

I'm using `Install-Package` to pull a nuget package to a target directory. Inside that directory is a subdirectory for target assembly and subdirectories for all of the dependencies of the target assembly.

I am using `Add-Type -Path $pathToAssembly` to load the target assembly, but it fails as the necessary dependencies aren't loaded.

I can iterate through the errors, adding each dependency, until all of the dependencies are included (with `Add-Type`). I end up with a number of `Add-Type` statements targetting the specific set of dependencies.

This solution is tightly bound to the version of the package I am pulling in. In this instance, it's all to do with API calls to TFS, so when we next update TFS, we may need to update the Nuget package version, which may have a different set of dependencies.

Is there a way of handling these dependencies more generically/gracefully? A programmatic solution or a native solution perhaps?